# Toggle all checkbox using a main button and itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a function that would check and unchecked all checkbox at once using a button. Works perfectly but whenever I toggle using itself (the current checkbox) it just wouldn't work.

In my Class component:

```
this.state = {
   checked: false
}
toggleCheck(i) {
    this.setState({ checked: i });
    if (this.state.checked === i) {
        this.setState({ checked: false })
    }
}
```

In my Function component

```
return(
   <div>
      {
         props.thisOne((v,i) => {
            return(<input checked={props.checked ? 'checked' : ''}/>)
         })
      }
      <button onClick={props.toggleCheck}>
   </div>
)
```

Any way to resolve this?

Comment: what is i supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

**1° - setState is asynchronous**

In the toggleCheck, you set a new state to the variable `checked` and right after, you try to use the variable `checked`, but in some cases, this variable may be not updated yet, what can lead to bugs. You can use the `callback` of `setState` in this case

React docs, about `setState` and `callback`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

**The input doesn't have a event handler**

In the input, you just have the `checked` props, but do not have a event handler such as `onChange`, so when you click in this checkbox, nothing occurs because, there's nothing to be done in this case. Add a event handler to the input to call a function when it is clicked and change the state, like you have done in the `button`

Comment: If you'd notice, I included "event-handling" in my tags. Hence, the missing event-handler. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that on toggling the current/active checkbox, there is no code which changes the current checkbox from checked to unchecked.

A probable better solution would be to have multiple states for each checkbox and use those to toggle using onChange on the checkbox itself.

```
<CustomInput globalCheck={globalCheckState} />
...
const CustomInput = (props) => {
   const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
   if (props.globalChek) {
     setCheck(true)
   }
   return (
     <input checked={check} onChange={() => setCheck(!check)} />
   )
}
```

This way you handle the local check state in a separate state. The `globalCheckState` can be toggled by using your button.

Comment: @Y M. the problem here is that I'm using a map function for the input. Even if I put a hander event, it will just keep on doing the same function.  Unless I alter the input's attribute to checked={props.checked === i ? 'checked' : ''} That'll work. But if I do that, the main button for check all will not work.

Comment: So, why not create a new component out of this and have a state there itself for the input. Let me add in the answer what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. Well, is it? I'm still a newbie... And I think I'm getting what you mean.

Comment: If I'd just create a new component for the input, I'll just pass the props that would toggle the checked state. It'll be the same

Comment: Yes, absolutely! But I thought you needed to toggle individually too. Hence the above code.

Comment: It's giving me an error saying "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."